# Responsive Image Cropping Desktop + Mobile + Tablet

Tags: php, jquery, css, image, crop

I'm using a plugin called CropIt: http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/

But I have one problem. I need the images to be responsive so I can crop them nicely in mobile devices.

How can I achieve a responsive image cropping?

Thanks.